# Directional Derivatives With Respect to Negative Vectors

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, big-picture

I understand this is probably a silly question but I'm with it struggling nonetheless. Consider the directional derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=1$ with respect to $u=-1$. I can see that this is equal to $-2$ but I struggle to relate this result with my notion of derivatives as slopes of tangent lines. Could someone explain, in elementary terms, how one should picture this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the direction $u = -1$, you have to look to the left, usually, you look to the right. So you could just flip your function...

And if you sit at $x = 1$, and go to the left, the function goes downwards, so the slope is negative.

Comment: So the slope at the same point is different? It doesn't make sense. The function go downwards but shouldn't the quotient also become negative so they cancel out?